# Hyperion Essbase 11.1.2.2 Unable to connect to Essbase Administrator Server from the Essbase Admin Console

Tags: oracle11g, hyperion, essbase

So I'm a newbie at Essbase - I've installed the EPM system - the Essbase admin services are up and running but for some reason, I'm not able to connect to the Admin Server through the EAS console. I get this error - `"Could not connect to Administration Service <IP>"`.

So I looked at the log file `-HyS9EPMServer-sysout.log`:

```
<Aug 2, 2012 9:48:43 AM EDT> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The Server has established connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service successfully.> 
<Aug 2, 2012 9:51:00 AM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 10.224.53.85:1,465 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<Aug 2, 2012 9:51:00 AM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 10.224.53.85:1,464 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<Aug 2, 2012 9:51:00 AM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 10.224.53.85:1,463 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
<Aug 2, 2012 9:51:05 AM EDT> <Warning> <Socket> <BEA-000449> <Closing socket as no data read from it on 10.224.53.85:1,470 during the configured idle timeout of 5 secs> 
[Lcom.brio.one.common.NetAddress;@3433a24
**<Aug 2, 2012 11:05:37 AM EDT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101017> <[ServletContext@37297592[app:SHAREDSERVICES module:interop path:/interop spec-version:2.5 version:11.1.2.0]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpSession is invalid**
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.check(SessionData.java:479)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.getAttribute(SessionData.java:392)
    at com.hyperion.cas.web.action.CASCommonAction.execute(CASCommonAction.java:112)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
**<Aug 2, 2012 11:05:37 AM EDT> <Notice> <Diagnostics> <BEA-320068> <Watch 'UncheckedException' with severity 'Notice' on server 'EPMServer0' has triggered at Aug 2, 2012 11:05:37 AM EDT. Notification details: 
WatchRuleType: Log 
WatchRule: (SEVERITY = 'Error') AND ((MSGID = 'WL-101020') OR (MSGID = 'WL-101017') OR (MSGID = 'WL-000802') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101020') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-101017') OR (MSGID = 'BEA-000802')) 
WatchData: DATE = Aug 2, 2012 11:05:37 AM EDT SERVER = EPMServer0 MESSAGE = [ServletContext@37297592[app:SHAREDSERVICES module:interop path:/interop spec-version:2.5 version:11.1.2.0]] Root cause of ServletException.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: HttpSession is invalid**
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.check(SessionData.java:479)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.session.SessionData.getAttribute(SessionData.java:392)
    at com.hyperion.cas.web.action.CASCommonAction.execute(CASCommonAction.java:112)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1198)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:416)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:821)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:301)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at com.hyperion.bpm.ServletFilter.doFilter(ServletFilter.java:93)
    at com.hyperion.bpm.logon.CredentialFilter.doFilter(CredentialFilter.java:81)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at com.hyperion.bpm.ServletFilter.doFilter(ServletFilter.java:93)
    at com.hyperion.bpm.LocalizationServletFilter.doFilter(LocalizationServletFilter.java:54)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter$1.run(JpsAbsFilter.java:119)
    at oracle.security.jps.util.JpsSubject.doAsPrivileged(JpsSubject.java:315)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.util.JpsPlatformUtil.runJaasMode(JpsPlatformUtil.java:442)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.runJaasMode(JpsAbsFilter.java:103)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsAbsFilter.doFilter(JpsAbsFilter.java:171)
    at oracle.security.jps.ee.http.JpsFilter.doFilter(JpsFilter.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at oracle.dms.servlet.DMSServletFilter.doFilter(DMSServletFilter.java:139)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3730)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3696)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2273)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2179)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1490)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
 SUBSYSTEM = HTTP USERID = <WLS Kernel> SEVERITY = Error THREAD = [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' MSGID = BEA-101017 MACHINE = SGT-ESSPLAN01 TXID =  CONTEXTID = 0000JZbrhSTAdL0_JxO5yf1G6Q2s0000WO TIMESTAMP = 1343919937388  
WatchAlarmType: AutomaticReset 
WatchAlarmResetPeriod: 30000
```

I cannot understand what the issue is since the server is up and running. I've searched high and low online and have found no solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be that EPM was installed with all services on one port (compact mode), then you have to state the port of the admin service. in compact mode all managed servers run on the same port (by default 9000).

Try to give (assuming your server is on localhost) :
localhost:9000

as the server name in the connection dialog